# Avoiding duplicated QuickCheck properties

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I'm starting to learn Haskell by doing the 99 Haskell problems.  http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems  I'd like to write tests for each program/function using quickcheck.

I have the following code:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
import Text.Printf

main  = mapM_ (\(s,a) -> printf "%-25s: " s >> a) tests

-- 1
myLast  lst = last lst
prop_1a xs x = myLast  (xs ++ [x]) == (x::String)

myLast' = head . reverse
prop_1b xs x = myLast' (xs ++ [x]) == (x::String)

tests  = [("1a",                 quickCheck prop_1a)
         ,("1b",                 quickCheck prop_1b)
         ]
```

I might write `myLast''`, `myLast'''`, etc.  Is there a way I can test all those methods without having to duplicate code and quickcheck properties?

Related question: Right now, I'm telling quickcheck to use Strings.  Is there a way to randomly use different types to test against?

Comment: Please _never_ use the word "method" as a synonym for "function"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can test all those methods without having to duplicate code and quickcheck properties?

Why not write the prop so that it takes a list of functions, and then does the check on each of them? Then you'd run it as `quickCheck (myProp [myLast, myLast', myLast''])`.

edit: I was afraid you might ask that :P To do it as I said above, `myProp` should take a list of functions, all of which have the same type as `last`, and return a boolean:

```
myProp :: [([a] -> a)] -> Bool
```

But now that I look at it, it might be better (and more analogous to your original approach) to have it also take a list and an item, so I think I'll do that instead:

```
myProp :: [([a] -> a)] -> [a] -> a -> Bool
```

If the list is empty then we return true:

```
myProp [] _ _ = True
```

If not, then we check whether the property holds for the first function in the list, then recursively check the rest of the list:

```
myProp [f:fs] xs x = f (xs ++ [x]) == x && myProp fs xs x
```

(I'm not sure why you wrote `x::String` in your implementation. I don't think you should need it -- `last` works on lists of anything, not just lists of Strings. But I haven't actually tested this out so I assume you had a good reason.)

Anyway, I think that should work but I haven't actually tried it. Please feel free to edit and fix any dumb syntax errors I may have made or whatever.

Comment: I'm having problems figuring out the syntax for doing that -- could you modify your answer to show that?

Comment: I added x::String because I needed to provide type information somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

Just take the function to test as another argument:

```
prop_1 last xs x = last (xs ++ [x]) == (x :: Int)

tests = zipWith mkTest ['a'..] [myLast, myLast']
  where mkTest letter func = ('1':[letter], quickCheck $ prop_1 func)
```